# Building glpk error: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, glpk

when trying to install glpk I get the following error. I've tried many things to solve it but I don't get to find a solution

```
Collecting glpk
  Using cached glpk-0.4.5.tar.gz (152 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
  Building wheel for glpk (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ruizm\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\ruizm\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\ruizm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk6uqubal'
       cwd: C:\Users\ruizm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k_surgky\glpk
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'glpk' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.5" -Ic:\users\ruizm\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\ruizm\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\glpk.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\glpk.obj
  glpk.c
  C:\Users\ruizm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k_surgky\glpk\src\lp.h(24): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'glpk.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Hey mate, did you ever figure it out? I've got the same problem